# Webpage fixed width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

After finishing the entire layout of my webpage using twitter bootstrap (all rows are fixed) - I would like to set the width to be fixed, that is for the layout to stay the same regardless of the browser size. 
That is, if the browser is too small, then only a part of the page will be visible.

My layout's structure is as follows

```
<body>

<div style="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="span4">
        </div>
        <div class="span8">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="span9"> </div>
<div class="span3"> </div>  

</div>
</body>
```

I've tried making a div that contains the container, and setting its position to absolute, but this doesn't keep the elements from moving when the browser is resized.

How I could do this?

Here is what is in head:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: Hey Julia. I think you mean `<div class="container">` (refer to your example code). Also - as your example suggests, you haven't included `bootstrap-responsive.css`, so don't listen to Owre.

Comment: You also shouldn't need the `"viewport"` meta tag if your website isn't going to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have included bootstrap-responsive.css in your html. Remove it! and then you can set your container to be whatever you want. `width: (x)px;`

Comment: YOu mean I included bootstrap-responsive css by setting the classes "container", "row" and "span"?

Comment: What css files have you included in head? You should include bootstrap.css but not bootstrap-responsive.css